# Return elements that are palindrome to each other in an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

How can I return an array of palindrome numbers in a given array? Not palindromic numbers like 11, 22, 33, 44, &c., but the numbers that are palindromic to other number in the same array. Assume all elements are positive and the result should not return single digit numbers (example below)

Let's say I have `array = [13, 31, 51, 79, 83, 97]`. Since 13 & 31 and 79 & 97 are palindromes, I want it to return `array_pali = [13, 31, 79, 97]`

```
def pali_array(array)
    array_reverse = array.map{|el| el.to_s.reverse.to_i}
    array_pali = array & array_reverse
    return array_pali
end
```

My initial plan is to come up with a reverse of that array, `array_reverse = array.map{|el| el.to_s.reverse.to_i}` and intersect them: `array & array_reverse`

A problem that occur is, if I want to return array of prime numbers from 2-100 as given:

```
array = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```

and I reversed it:

```
array_reverse = array.map{|el| el.to_s.reverse.to_i}
=> [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 31, 71, 91, 32, 92, 13, 73, 14, 34, 74, 35, 95, 16, 76, 17, 37, 97, 38, 98, 79]
```

It returns:

```
array & array_reverse
=> [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 31, 37, 71, 73, 79, 97]
```

The problem with this approach:

2, 3, 5, 7, and 11 are not palindromes to other elements. The reverse of single digit number is that number itself and it causes the code to return all single digit numbers, and all palindromic number (like 11, 22, 33). It should return only `[13, 17, 31, 37, 71, 73, 79, 97]`

How can I make it to return *only* elements that are palindromic *to other element* in the same array?

Comment: Just add another filter step to remove palindromic numbers

Comment: There's no such thing as "palindromic to". 1, 121, and 12321 are all [by definition palindromes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindromic_number). 13 and 31 are not "palindromic", they're just the same numbers with the digits reversed.

Comment: I just saw this question and was surprised to see that you selected an answer after only 35 minutes! Why not hold off for at least a couple of hours to encourage other answers. There's no rush you know.

Comment: @CarySwoveland : my apologies. I am still learning the proper etiquette of SO; so if I rush too early to approve something, I will hold off for longer time next time. Thanks for pointing it out! Retrospectively, I have in the past put off selecting an answer for a few hours after receiving my first response. I was waiting for a "better" response, but it never came. In the end, because I waited too long, I ended up not rewarding/ forgetting the only responder I have. This is why I lean towards selecting response hastily than too slow. Suggestions are welcome! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think this works if you want an alternative:

```
array = [13, 31, 51, 79, 83, 97]
array.combination(2)
     .select {|pair| pair.first.to_s == pair.last.to_s.reverse }
     .flatten

#=> [13, 31, 79, 97]
```

Use [`Array#combination`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-combination) to get every pair combo then we *select* only those palindrome-pairs. Then just flatten your array.

Comment: O(N^2). Doubling the input quadruples run time :)

Comment: True. For the purpose of what I am doing, Big O does not really matter. Good catch though!!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very naive and lazy implementation. Doesn't preserve original order of elements. Should be O(N).

I hope the code is self-explanatory.

```
array = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]

require 'set'
seen_numbers = Set.new
result = []

array.each do |elem|
  next if elem < 10

  normal_str = elem.to_s
  rev_str = normal_str.reverse

  if seen_numbers.include?(rev_str)
    result << rev_str.to_i
    result << elem
  end

  seen_numbers << normal_str
end

result # => [13, 31, 17, 71, 37, 73, 79, 97]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [7, 13, 31, 51, 31, 60, 70, 13, 79, 83, 79, 97]
```

Notice that there are various duplicate values in `arr`.

```
arr.reject { |n| n < 10 || (n%10).zero? }.
    group_by { |n| n.to_s.each_char.sort }.
    values.
    reject { |arr| arr.size == 1 }.
    flat_map { |arr| arr.group_by(&:itself).values.min_by(&:size) }
  #=> [13, 13, 97]
```

The matching values are easy enough to calculate if required.

`|| (n%10).zero?` was added just to speed things up a bit.

The steps are as follows.

```
a = arr.reject { |n| n < 10 || (n%10).zero? }
  #=> [13, 31, 51, 31, 13, 79, 83, 79, 97] 
b = a.group_by { |n| n.to_s.each_char.sort }
  #=> {["1", "3"]=>[13, 31, 31, 13], ["1", "5"]=>[51],
  #    ["7", "9"]=>[79, 79, 97], ["3", "8"]=>[83]} 
c = b.values
  #=> [[13, 31, 31, 13], [51], [79, 79, 97], [83]] 
d = c.reject { |arr| arr.size == 1 }
  #=> [[13, 31, 31, 13], [79, 79, 97]] 
d.flat_map { |arr| arr.group_by(&:itself).values.min_by(&:size) }
  #=> [13, 13, 97]
```

Consider the last step. `flat_map` passes the first element of `d` to its block and sets the block variable to that value:

```
arr = d[0]
  #=> [13, 31, 31, 13]
```

and performs the block calculation:

```
e = arr.group_by(&:itself)
  #=> {13=>[13, 13], 31=>[31, 31]}
f = e.values
  #=> [[13, 13], [31, 31]]
f.min_by(&:size)
  #=> [13, 13]
```

Next,

```
arr = d[1]
  #=> [79, 79, 97]
e = arr.group_by(&:itself)
  #=> {79=>[79, 79], 97=>[97]} 
f = e.values
  #=> [[79, 79], [97]] 
f.min_by(&:size)
  #=> [97]
```

`flat_map` therefore returns

```
[*[13, 13], *[97]]
  #=> [13, 13, 97]
```